# An example for a finite hypothesis class which is not PAC learnable?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

Finite hypothesis class with bounded loss function are PAC learnable. Are there examples for finite hypothesis classes in the case of unbounded loss function, which aren't PAC learnable?

Comment: Cross-posted on cs.se: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/an-example-for-a-finite-hypothesis-class-which-is-not-pac-learnable.